# How to solve the differential equation $y' + \sec(x)*y = \tan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am really struggling to solve the differential equation: $y' + \sec(x)y = \tan(x)$. If someone could point me in the right direction or give me a step by step plan it would be much appreciated!

So far I have tried taking the common factor to be $\exp(\int(\sec(x))$  (which simplifies to $\tan(x)+\sec(x)+c$ if I am not mistaken) however I end up with an equation which is beyond my integration abilities because it has both $X$ and $Y$ in it. I'm not sure if it is a case of trig identities or imaginary numbers which are letting me down.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you familiar with the integrating factor method?

Comment: Is this a homework problem or do you just need the answer? You can see the answer [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2By%2Fcos(x)%3Dtan(x))

Comment: I don't think so - I have only used a 'common factor' and then a 'particular integral' - I'm not sure if this is the same thing just worded differently?

Comment: It seems like you've misunderstood the role of the integrating factor. Let $h(x) = \exp \left(\int \sec x \mathrm{d}x \right)$. Multiplying by $h$ on both sides gives you $hy' + (\sec x )hy  = (hy)' = h(x)\tan x \iff hy = \int h(x) \tan x ~\mathrm{d} x$, and the latter integral is only in $x$.

Comment: There is an exact formula to solve this type of ode!!  See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation).  Have not you been taught this method?

Comment: I already mentioned this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645407/how-might-i-go-about-forming-a-general-solution-for-the-following-differential-e/1645566#1645566).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the form of a [Linear Differential Equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx)

and here the integrating factor would be $e^{\int(\sec(x))}$ so that you will get $$\begin{align}
(\tan(x)+\sec(x))\frac{dy}{dx}+(\tan(x)+\sec(x))y\sec(x) = &\, \tan^2(x)+\sec(x)\tan(x) \\
((\tan(x)+\sec(x))y)' = & \\
\end{align}$$

So integrating on both sides you have, $$(\tan(x)+\sec(x))y=\tan(x)+\sec(x)-x+C$$ $$y=\frac{\tan(x)+\sec(x)-x+C}{\tan(x)+\sec(x)}.$$

I have just outlined what you need to do here, you can go to the hyperlink given to know more about linear differential equations. Hope it helps.

**EXTRA EDITS:**

Links to the integrals: [integrating factor](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sec%28x%29), and the [integral of the right side](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=tan%5E2%28x%29%2Bsecxtanx). For both links, press the `Go!`button next to the formula.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, the integrating factor is
$$\exp\left(\int\sec x\,dx\right)
    = \exp\left(-\ln(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)) + \ln(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2))\right)
    = \frac{\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)}
    = \frac{\cos x}{(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))^2}.$$
Multiplying both sides by the integrating factor gives
\begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dx}\left(y\frac{\cos x}{(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))^2}\right) 
    &= \tan x\cdot\frac{\cos x}{(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))^2} \\
    &= \frac{\sin x}{(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))^2} \\
    &= \frac{\sin x}{1 - 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)} \\
    &= \frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}.
\end{align*}
Now just integrate both sides.

Comment: Thank you, I will need to brush up on my half angle formulae!